# Excel: How to add the same value for row pattern

Tags: excel, count, row, formula, calculated-columns

I have a table with 2 columns: "ID" and "Continue?".
I need to fill the 3rd row like that:

- If column B is `Y`, copy the `ID` (column A's value) into column C.
- Else, write the last copied value into column C.

In my picture you can see an example of the expected result.

[image: Expected results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Cell C2` enter the following formula and drag/copy it down as required.

```
=IF(B1="Y",C1,A2)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatly I have a table with 7000 rows with this situation and I don't want to do it manually :)

Comment: @risk_ltu - You don't have to do this manually for 7000 rows. Just enter 1 in `Cell C2` and then enter formula in `Cell C3` then drag it down till row 7000.

Comment: Hey, I tried and it worked! Wow, you are my personal superman! :D

Answer (score 0):

Put this in cell C2 and fill `=IF(EXACT(B1,"Y"),C1,A2)`

Comment: Sorry, this one did not work. Answer by @Mrig is the right one.

Comment: The two answers are the same, except that I insisted on an uppercase 'Y'.  But glad you got your problem sorted!